# How to install Anaconda in a CGP Cloud AI Notebook instance so that it is used by jupyter lab

Tags: gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I am using a Google Cloud AI Notebook and want to use conda (and some other non-standard packages). So, I tried installing it via an Anaconda script (e.g. https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-2019.10-Linux-x86_64.sh) by

- using a terminal in Jupyter lab (user: jupyter)
- ssh-ing into the compute engine instance (user: my_name)

Both processes completed successfully, but have no effect on the kernel used by the Notebooks.

Probably, I need to somehow "tell" the Juypter instance started by "OPEN JUPYTERLAB" to use the conda kernels instead of the default one, but I could not find out, how to do that.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: what steps did you use to install conda?

Answer (score 2):

Open a terminal window in Jupyter and do the following:

```
pip install ipykernel
```

Making sure it's the same `pip` as the one your notebook is using. In my case I had to use `pip3`.

Then in the same terminal, make sure you're in your **conda** environment and run:

```
ipython kernel install --user --name=projectname
```

Finally, go to the Cloud AI Notebook console, select your machine, and hit **Reset**. Your Jupyter notebook should now list your conda kernels.

Useful links:

- [Using jupyter notebooks with a virtual environment](https://anbasile.github.io/programming/2017/06/25/jupyter-venv/)

Comment: Thanks for your support and sorry for the late reply. Works like a charm!